# Non-locally compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its compactification

Tags: general-topology

> Find a non-locally compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has a compactification $K$ such that $K\setminus A$ is has the discrete topology.

I know that the Alexandroff compactification $X^*$ of $X$ has the property that $X^*\setminus X$ has the discrete topology. But I think this is rather irrelevant.

Comment: No, because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not compact.

Comment: @DuncanRamage: Not only that, $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^c\times\mathbb{Q}^c$ with the subspace topology is not the discrete topology. Hence, I just decided to delete the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the definition of locally compact: every point in the set has a compact neighborhood.

Thinking of the case in $\mathbb{R}$, wouldn't the following work?
Let $A=[0,1]\setminus \{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. It is not locally compact because every neighborhood of $0$ fails to be closed. The interval $[0,1]$ would be a compactification. But $[0,1]\setminus A=\{1/n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Then you can construct something very similar in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Work with a box instead of an interval.

Comment: Makes sense, give that there is a homeomorphism $h$ so that $h(A)$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Do you know of such? I.e. $A$ needs to be densely embedded into $[0,1]$.

Comment: $A$ as defined is already dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, after looking at it I realized to just take the inclusion mapping. Thanks :)

Comment: +1. In $\Bbb R^2$ you can simply take the $A$ of your answer and consider $A\times \{0\}$.

Comment: @Anguepa: Note that there are actually [several definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) of local compactness, not all of which are equivalent. Fortunately, they all **are** equivalent in Hausdorff spaces and hence certainly in metric spaces.